# Texturing the Malwiya

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]
I am working on a project to texture the Malwiya using the same original material but I'm having a problen when I klicked on UV Mapping and by using the Project from view (Bounds) method the result was that: [image] [image]

How to fix that and turn my 3D model to look like the Malwiya in the image?

Comment: I suspect that your material nodes aren't setup correctly, it's probably using generated co-ordinates.  Post a screengrab of your node setup.  You want a Input->Texture-Coordinates node to wire the UV value to your image texture node.

Comment: Hi @Merlin Can please explain more what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Without seing your shader setup, it is difficult to provide a definitive answer, but I will try based on what you have provided so far.

In the shading tab, add a new node for texture coordinates and wire it into the 
normal of your image texture.

Blender needs to know how to apply the image, you have specified UV unwrwap, so you need to tell the shader where to get that information.

[image: Shader node setup]